# How to find rows with the largest value in a group?

Tags: sqlite

I have a db_table who looks something like this:

```
description     external_id    value      highest
sample_text1    123456         abc        0
sample_text2    125435         def        0
sample_text3    987654         abc        0
sample_text4    123456         def        0
sample_text5    123456         ghj        0
```

I would like to filter out the ones who have the same `external_id` and give the one who has the highest `value` based on a pattern I want for this example (from lowest to highest abc, def, ghj) the value 1. The ones who don't have other entries with the same value in that column also get a 1.

So the table should look like this:

```
description     external_id    value      highest
sample_text1    123456         abc        0
sample_text2    125435         def        1
sample_text3    987654         abc        1
sample_text4    123456         def        0
sample_text5    123456         ghj        1
```

Comment: so where you're stuck ? what have you tried ?

Comment: well to be honest... i am learning about sqlite3 since a few days now... I only know how to create tables, write date tables, ignore if they alredy exist (unique value) and read all of the data out. but comparison like this... i dont really know where to start...

Answer (score 1):

You want to update only those rows that have the largest `value` for the same `external_id`, i.e., those rows for which no other row with the same `external_id` but a smaller `value` exists:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET highest = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                  WHERE T2.external_id = MyTable.external_id
                    AND T2.value       < MyTable.value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CL. for your answer. I actually had to google to understand your sqlite. Since I am not so advanced with sqlite yet. But how does sqlite know what is higher? How can I define that?

Comment: [Sort order](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order). Or what do you mean?

Comment: yeah, but abc def ghj is sorted normally a before d, d before g, but what if I would have crazy values like:

eb = 2
af = 3
xa = 1

Comment: Then you need to compare them in a different way.